# Hamiltonian vector field proof?

Tags: manifolds, symplectic-geometry

Given a manifold $M$ and a symplectic form $\omega \in \Omega^2(M)$, let $j:Y\to M$ be a symplectic submanifold (i.e, $j^*\omega \in \Omega^2(Y)$). Now, let $H \in C^{\infty}(M)$ be a smooth function such that $$\xi_{H}\lvert_x \in T_xY$$ for all $x \in Y$.

How does one prove (or start to prove) that $\xi_H \lvert_Y$ is the Hamiltonian vector field of the function $H\lvert_Y \in C_{\infty}(Y)$ with respect to $j^*\omega$? Thanks for any help folks.

Comment: What have you tried? If you just write the definitions of being a Hamiltonian vector field of $H$ on$M$ and of $j^*H$ on $Y$ and compare them you should be able to get what you want.

Comment: I’m aware of the definition in terms of the Poisson bracket - is this the one you’re telling me to use?  Or, do you mean the one in terms of exterior derivatives?

Comment: I see. In the symplectic case the definition $\omega(\xi_H, \cdot)=dH(\cdot)$ (up to sign convention) is the one that is often taught, and is the one I was referring to.

Comment: Ok, so that looks like the definition for the Hamiltonian vector field of $H$ on $M$. How would the one of $j^*H$ on $Y$ differ? I’m having trouble writing it down confidently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume $j$ is an embedding.

Let $\xi_Y \in TY$ be the unique vector field with $j_*\xi=\xi_H$.  You need to show (up to sign conventions) that for all $\eta$ tangent to $Y$ one has $[j^*\omega](\xi_Y, \eta)=[-d(j^*H)](\eta)=[-j^*(dH)](\eta)$ for all $\eta \in TY$; this is  the same as $\omega(\xi_H, j_* \eta)=-d(H)(j_*\eta)$. But since $\xi_H$ is Hamiltonian vector field of $H$, this is true for all $\nu$ (tangent to $M$ at points of $j(Y)$), hence in particular for $\nu=j_*\eta$.

In the more traditional order of mathematical argument:

1) Since $\xi_H$ is Hamiltonian vector field of $H$, we have (up to sign conventions) for all $\nu$ tangent to $M$ at points of $j(Y)$

$$\omega(\xi_H, \nu)=-d(H)(\nu)$$

2) In particular the above holds for $\nu=j_*\eta$, where  $\eta$ is any vector field tangent to $Y$. Plugging in we get

$$\omega(\xi_H, j_*\eta)=-d(H)(j_*\eta)$$

3) If we now define the vector field $\xi_Y$ tangent to $Y$ via $\xi_H=j_*\xi_Y$ (which we can, since  $\xi_H$ is tangent to $j(Y)$ and any vector field tangent to $j(Y)$ is a pushforward of unique tangent vector field of $Y$), then the above becomes

$$\omega(j_*\xi_Y, j_*\eta)=-d(H)(j_*\eta)$$

or

$$(j^{*}\omega)(\xi_Y, \eta)=-d(j^* H)(\eta)$$

Since $\eta$ was arbitrary, we can write this as

$$(j^{*}\omega)(\xi_Y, \cdot)=-d(j^* H)(\cdot)$$

which precisely says that $\xi_Y$ is the Hamiltonian vector field of $j^* H$ with respect to the symplectic form  $j^{*}\omega$, as we wanted.

Comment: This seems much easier than I thought it would be. Thanks a lot for your insight, Max.

Comment: In general, the Hamiltonian vector field for $H|_Y$ will be obtained from one for $H$ by projecting to $TY$ along the symplectic-orthogonal complement of $TY$ (which is complementary to $TY$ since that is a symplectic subspace). The proof is basically the same.

Comment: Hi Max, sorry to bug you again. I’ve returned to finish my proof of this question (got occupied for a while), and I’m a bit stuck on how to show the part regarding $\eta$ being tangent to $Y$. Can you possibly give me any guidance? I would appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Here $\eta$ is an arbitrary vector field tangent to $Y$ which appears in the definition of Hamiltonian vector field for $H|_Y=H\cdot j$.  In other words, in the formula $j^* \omega(\xi_Y, \cdot)=d(j^*H)(\cdot)$ one replaces the $\cdot$ by arbitrary $\eta$ tangent to $Y$;  so we don't need to show it's tangent to $Y$, it just is.

Comment: I meant that, for $\eta$ tangent to $Y$, you said to show the identity above holds. Showing the identity is what has stuck me.

Comment: We are trying to show that identity. That is the goal. Everything that was is written after  this identity is the argument showing it. I have now edited the answer to give the argument in the more traditional "from premises to conclusion" way.

Comment: You’re the best, Max. Thanks so much.